# How do I put text in a hex

Tags: java, hex

I'm making a strategy game based on a hex grid.
I've created a hexGrid using a code written by salamander2.
Code is on GitHub: `https://gist.github.com/salamander2/4329783.`
My problem is to put text that I want into a hex grid. It doesn't have to be a string.
All i want from it is to show number of built building on a hex.
This is what author has used for displaying on hexes.

```
board [int][int] = (int) 'w';
```

This will show "w" on a hex.

I've tried:

```
board[int][int] = hex.getBuildingList.size();
```

But it doesn't show the specific number.
As for a code, I've tried it in Sysytem.print and it shows right figure for each hex.
Can any one help me please?
I've tried something like this:

```
Integer bN = hex.getBuildingList().size();
                    String b = stringToHex(bN.toString());

                    board[p.x][p.y] = b;
```

But it gives me an error, that b is string not int.

Answer (score 0):

```
static public String stringToHex(String s) {
        char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
        String next;
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            next = Integer.toHexString((int)chars[i]);
            // Unfortunately, toHexString doesn't pad with zeroes, so we have to.
            for (int j = 0; j < (4-next.length()); j++)  {
                output.append("0");
            }
            output.append(next);
        }
        return output.toString();
    }
```

The source is at below link. I came across this while working on bulkSMS
http://developer.bulksms.com/eapi/code-samples/java/unicode/

Comment: I'm still implementing it. I will keep You posted. Give me 5 minutes.